# xcrun simctl status_bar not working in xcode 12

Tags: xcode, statusbar, simulator, xcrun, simctl

I have just upgraded my Xcode to 12 beta. I have tried to override the status bar on the simulator using this command:

```
xcrun simctl status_bar  52B135BF-F549-4684-A959-914499AB3296  override --time '9:41' --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 100;
```

This command works on the previous version. However, it doesn't work anymore.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You can just say booted instead the big long identifier. Or use the sim name.

Comment: I just ran `xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time '9:41' --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 100` and it works fine. Voting to close as being unreproducible.

Comment: It did not work on my mac. I ask to see if anybody has the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Xcode 12b3 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-beta-release-notes): "simctl status bar overrides don’t work properly on simulated devices running iOS or iPadOS 13.6 or earlier. (63958080)"

Just got burned by this myself.

Comment: Documented as not working with Xcode 13 Beta 2 as well:

>Status bar overrides are unavailable in simulated devices. (78155601)